# Not able to find external files

Tags: file

I'm a rookie programmer and am having trouble directing my compiler to find certain image files using const char.

I'm reading through a book, "Programming 2D Games" by C. Kelly, and when I look through his 
code, he uses this line to find his image file.

const char NEBULA_IMAGE[] = "pictures\NasaNebula.jpg";  // photo source nasaimages.org

When I do this I get an error that I cannot find the file. However if I use this line:

const char NEBULA_IMAGE[] = "E:/TestProject/pictures/NasaNebula.jpg"; //Photo source nasa

It works. Could someone let me know how I can configure my project so that it can find these files without defining their exact path? I've looked around for a while but can't find exactly what I need.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since that path is used at runtime (not at compile time) to locate and load that file you have to make sure that such a *relative* path makes sense from the current situation. You have to make sure that the *current working directory* of your application is such, that *from that directory on* the relative path leads to the file.

In your specific example the applications working directiory must be in `E:/TestProject`, so that the relative path `pictures/NasaNebula.jpg` leads to the full (and correct) path `E:/TestProject/pictures/NasaNebula.jpg`.

In general relative path offer a lot of flexibility. For example by using *diffferent resource folders* at runtime, thus using different files without having to change the source code of the application. But relative path also demand that the current situation of the app allows to resolve such paths.